# alter drupal 7 view query

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I want to access two more columns so i want to change my view query, I am using following code its not changing at all, I created my own module and used this.

```
function aaa_views_api() { // your module name into hook_views_api
  return array(
    'api' => 3,    
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'aaa'),
  );
}


function jobs_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_name') {
   drupal_set_message("I am in");   

    $view->build_info['query'] = "SELECT a,b,c FROM tbl";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What kind of field you're trying to add ? If you trying to add fields from a custom DB table, I would recommend you to use hook_views_data to describe that table and make it visible in Views so you don't need to alter it. See https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/7 If you still need to modify the query via hook_views_query_alter you should be modifying the $query object.

Answer (score 0):

For starters if you want to modify the query you need to modify the $query object.

Also your hook function name in this example would be
    aaa_views_query_alter()

You could try following this example
http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/drupal-7-how-modify-views-query-custom-module